# Solving a nonlinear equation $\sum_{z=0}^{s} \frac{(\lambda(l-x))^z}{z!} e^{-\lambda(l-x)}=p$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion, nonlinear-optimization

I would appreciate it if someone helps me with solving the following equation.
Suppose $\lambda,l \in R^+$, $p\in[0,1]$, and $s\in N_{0}$. How can we find an $x\in [0,l]$, which satisfies the following equation:

$$\sum_{z=0}^{s} \frac{(\lambda(l-x))^z}{z!} e^{-\lambda(l-x)}=p$$

or

$$F(s,\lambda(l-x))=p,$$ where $F(.,\lambda(l-x))$ is Poisson CDF with mean $\lambda(l-x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering $$\sum_{z=0}^{s} \frac{(\lambda(l-x))^z}{z!} e^{-\lambda(l-x)}=p$$ I would suggest to change variable $\lambda(l-x)=t$ which makes $$\sum_{z=0}^{s}\frac{e^{-t} t^z}{z!}=p$$ which simplifies to $$\frac{\Gamma (s+1,t)}{s!}=p$$ where appears the incomplete Gamma function.

So, given $s$ and $p$, this is the equation to be solved. If $p\leq 1$, you will find a solution but you would more than likely use a numerical method as  @gt6989b already answered.

**Edit**

Playing with the equation using $p=\frac 12$, it is amazing to find that the solution is almost $$t \approx s+\frac 23$$ For example, using $s=20$, this gives $t=\frac{62}{3}\approx 20.6667$ while the "exact" solution is $\approx 20.6676$.

Comment: How did you find $t≈s+\frac{2}{3}$ for $p=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Serkewtin. Just looking at the first terms.

Comment: I am just looking for an approximation, but I didn't get your point :(. You meant which first terms?

Comment: I just solved using Newton method for $s=1,2,3,\cdots,10$ and observed.

Answer (score 0):

Even if $x$ was not in the exponent, this would be a polynomial equation of degree $s$, there is no analytic solutions for $s \ge 5$. This way, it is nonlinear even for $s=1$.

However, because the LHS is continuous and differentiable in $x$, you can use a variety of numerical methods, like bisection or Newton's method, to numerically approximate the root if it exists.

Comment: Thank you so much. You meant there is an analytic solution for $s \leq 4$ ?